# argparse, subcommands, and inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, argparse

I use `argparse` (Python 3) to execute one of the subcommands.

I want to initialize a class instance of a class which depends on the chosen subcommand. (However, all these classes have a common base class which contains fields common for all subcommands.)

For example for `chain` subcommand I want to fill values in an object of `TransformationAutomaticWorkflowElementOptions` class.

The question: What is a good way to create the object of the right type dependently on the user's subcommand? and how to fill its fields (both common fields of the base class (see options common for all subparsers) and special fields of this particular derived class) then?

*The problem is to call the constructor determined by a particular subcommand before processing all other options.*

Below is an (almost) real code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                 description="Automatically process XML.")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands')

parser.add_argument('-p', '--preload', help='preload asset', action='append', metavar='NAMESPACE')
parser.add_argument('-r', '--recursive', help='recursive download mode (none, breadth-first, depth-first)',
                    choices=['none', 'breadth', 'depth'])
parser.add_argument('-x', '--recursive-order', metavar='ORDER',
                    help='recursive download order (comma separated "sources", "targets", "workflowtargets")')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--downloaders', metavar='DOWNLOADERS',
                    help='a plus-separated list of comma-separated lists of "builtin","ns"')

chain_parser = subparsers.add_parser('chain', aliases=['c'], help='Automatically run a chain of transformations')
chain_parser.add_argument('source', nargs='?', help='source document (defaults to stdin)')
chain_parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', nargs=1, help='output file (defaults to stdout)')
chain_parser.add_argument('-t', '--target', help='target namespace(s)', action='append', metavar='NAMESPACE')
chain_parser.add_argument('-n', '--not-in-target', help='what if a result is not in target NS',
                          choices=['ignore', 'remove', 'error'])
chain_parser.add_argument('-u', '--universal-precedence', help='universal precedence', metavar='URL')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Your example code is neither very terse nor very illustrative.

Comment: Currently the only solution I conceived is to first run `args = parser.parse_args()` and only after this create and initialize the class instance

Comment: `argparse` doesn't call any constructor, it just parses the input and returns values in the `args` namespace.  I'd suggest printing that.  Use `args.title` to identify that `chain` was the choice, and then call the constructor as you normally would.

Comment: Consider also click lib: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/quickstart/#nesting-commands

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to initialize the class instance before processing any arguments because arguments come in their order in the user-provided command.

The only solution remained is to first parse all args and only then initialize the class instance using already parsed `args` produced by `args = parser.parse_args()`.

Comment: This is extremely vague and unlikely to be useful to future readers.